# Joomla DT Register - Which file need to change to customize the registration form of an event

Tags: joomla, customization

I have a Joomla site with DT Register 3.3.2 and I would need to customize a little the layout of the event registration form for frontend site.
Which file do I have to edit?

Kind regards,
Matteo

Comment: Matteo can you offer a bit more detail about the task you are undertaking?  Do you know about [joomla.se] Stack Exchange?  It is the designated place to post Joomla support questions.  A direct link to this community can be found in your site's backend Help menu.  Try your question there.

Comment: Hello @mickmackusa I need simply to format in a different way the position and formatting of some fields, so I would need to customize the view that generate the event registration form.